# Free web-scraper tools for research studies

Tags: web-apps, data-analysis, web

first time here.

For my thesis I need to retrieve reviews from some websites. At present I'm using webscraper.io, but I have a problem: I would like to use a script/program to scrape every day or also every week in order to collect **automatically** more data.

The website from which I collect data isn't dynamic, so I need to modify everytime the link of the main page. It takes too long and it requires human assistance.

Can you help me? Are there any other free web data extraction tools?

Thanks

Comment: Can you code (Python)?

Comment: @Mawg not a very expert programmer but yes I can

Comment: Then, [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) is probably your best bet; or, maybe [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)